# Is there a well-defined notion of "maximally correlated" probability distribution on $[a,b]^2$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, dirac-delta

For some interval $[a, b]$ of the real line, consider the family of probability distributions $p: [a,b]\times [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $p\geq 0$ and $\int dx dy p(x, y) = 1$. So $p(x, y)$ can be interpreted as the probability (density) for sampling a pair $(x, y) \in [a,b]^2$.

Is there any well-defined notion of a maximally correlated distribution (call it $p^*$) that assigns a higher probability density to the outcome $(x, x)$ than any other possible distribution $p$? Naively, the following seems like a possible choice:

$$
p^* (x, y) = q(x) \delta(x - y) \tag{1}
$$

where $q(x)$ is appropriately normalized and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

What is wrong with the distribution $(1)$, and what kind of better choice/reasoning could be used to describe a "maximally correlated" probability density in the above sense?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot have a density that is only positive on the diagonal, but you can come arbitrarily close. If you don't require the existence of a density, there are a lot of distributions supported on the diagonal.

Comment: Is there a formal way of describing a density that gets 'arbitrarily close' to the one I have in mind?

Comment: Sure, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a density $f$ with the property that $f(x,y)>0$ implies that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $\epsilon.$